# Read CSV file into pandas dataframe from FTPS server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am unable to grab the data from a CSV file to be able to put it into a pandas dataframe. I am able to get into the directory and see all of the files there, but I haven't been able to access the document.

Here is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import socket
import pandas as pd

server=ftplib.FTP_TLS(‘server’,certfile = r'C:/’)
server.login(user,pw)


# get into respective directory
server.cwd('Banana')
server.prot_p()


# This piece here is needed in order to see what is in my directory, I don't understand why. 
# Something about the server not being set up correctly?

server.af = socket.AF_INET6

# check location

server.pwd()

# check files 

server.dir()

# Get CSV file data

import io
download_file = io.BytesIO()
download_file.seek(0)
server.retrbinary('RETR ' + str('file.csv'), download_file.write)
download_file.seek(0)
file_to_process = pd.read_csv(download_file, engine='python')
```

The error that I get is that the last code from import io down to file_to_process just sits there and does nothing. Maybe it times itself out? Unsure the issue.
New error is this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3376: character maps to <undefined>
```

Edit: Now I'm trying to save to disk. But this code deletes the contents of the file. Do I not understand how write works?

```
filematch = ‘Try20.csv’
target_dir = r'\\server’
import os

for filename in server.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
            server.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)
```

Secondarily, I don't understand how to write the contents of fhandle into a dataframe now.

Comment: Try to save the file to disk first and see if the file is OK.

Comment: @jurez I added my edit. Don't understand how to get fhandle into a dataframe and how to not delete the contents of the CSV file as well.